# â€ appearing instead of quotation marks

Tags: css, html

In my code I have quotes around text in a p element. The quotation mark at the end does not show up, instead I see these 2 characters: â€ . See image for more details.
Does anyone know the source of this problem or could offer any help? (I had a similar problem with quotation marks at the front a while back, which got fixed after adding margin-left; this p element already has margin-right and margin-left).

[image: p element where the problem is present]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Thank you it works beautifully... Now is it possible to get the same type of quotation in front?
Here is how it currently looks:
http://i.imgur.com/WgmbZo3.png

Comment: Maybe you could use other kind of unicode, it depends on the font or style do you want. If you want exploid that aspect of your html experience in fonts, you could ask about otf or google fonts in stack graphic design

Comment: To be more specific, I just want the quotation marks to match basically xD (aka turn the first quotation mark into the same style as the second one)

Is that what I should ask in stack graphic design?

Comment: Cheetaiean: You probably want a `U+201F DOUBLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK`, which looks like `‟`, or a `U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK`, which looks like `“`.

Comment: McanGeest: Yes, something like that. Any tips on how to do that? 
(i.e. do I change a css element? html element? lol I'm still fairly newb at web design so excuse my question)

Comment: Will the above (ex. U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK ) work if I use the <q> property? (which I'm not using atm)

Comment: You can just copy the examples from my comment above (the actual characters, of course, not their names) and paste them in your code. If your editor can handle them (and it probably can, since it could handle the closing quotation mark), it should work as you'd expect.

Comment: @MvanGeest I'll glad if you want edit my answer to improve your specifications

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. Aside from copying pasting the U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK I found out that it is 'registered' as a html entity and you can use &ldquo; for the left and &rdquo; for the right (i.e. like you would use &nbsp) No more questions lol

Comment: @Leandro Feel free to insert that information into your answer yourself :) I wouldn't know exactly how I would phrase it, considering the question wasn't originally about fancy quotes.